# Project Image across immense distance?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Couldn't think of a good title for this question, sorry in advance.

I have a situation where I'd like to have a wizard doing his wizard thing off in a tower somewhere, however he has somehow enchanted a flask to summon a controllable illusion of himself at any distance across any plane.

I need help with the somehow - I don't want to run it "just because", i'd like magic to back it up if possible.

To put in context, the wizard will be getting his flask 'found' by the adventuring party, and they will be able to interact with him. He will be claiming that he is trapped within the flask - if anyone has any suggestions for a believable magical explanation for this, along the lines of magic required to trap someone in a flask, then that'd be appreciated too, but it's less important as it's not the truth in the game world.

Comment: Do you mean physically interact like they can rub the flask and the wizard's projection pops out and starts giving high fives and casting?  Or is it more like they can just see and talk to him?   If it is option 2, then maybe some sort of scrying device "attuned" to the wizard and the wizard has the opposite end of the device that allows him to scry back at the party.  http://paizo.com/prd/spells/scrying.html

Comment: He is not required to cast, he is just required to speak, but yes, like that. The Project Image spell sounds something along the lines i'd like (thought the range is limited), but i'm reasonably new to D&D/Pathfinder and hoping someone can explain a logical explanation on how this could be 'legit'.

Comment: Scrying sounds along the lines, however I need an illusory representation - is there a RAW approach to enchanting an object to create an illusion with Project Image that can then be controlled/communicated  (perhaps scrying..?) over an infinite distance? It's just that scrying innately doesn't have a illusory representation from my understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of anything that could produce an illusion like this.  I immediately thought of scrying as the closest thing possible but you would have to fudge it a bit (perhaps make a new spell/ability based off of scrying) to get it to work.  I am fairly new to Pathfinder though so somebody else may know of a different trick to get this to work using something that exists in game.

Comment: So--I'm clarifying here--*via* this item the wizard will claim he's trapped in the flask but also be able to make an interactive illusion of himself *outside* the flask--and all the while the wizard's on his couch back at his tower?

Comment: Claiming that hes trapped in and when the party interacts with the flask it will summon him, although in reality, yeah, hes on his couch and just projecting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, there are a few things that you could do here, but I will highlight one specific method.

Let's start from the more complicated part: The Flask.

You can use the Metamorphosis option from the spell [Binding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/binding.htm) to trap a creature inside an object (like a flask) such that it will be able to communicate:

> *Metamorphosis*
>
> The subject assumes gaseous form, except for its head or
> face. It is held harmless in a jar or other container, which may be
> transparent if you so choose. The creature remains aware of its
> surroundings and can speak, but it cannot leave the container, attack,
> or use any of its powers or abilities. The binding is permanent. The
> subject does not need to breathe, eat, or drink while metamorphosed,
> nor does it age.

Now - obviously the Wizard will not want to trap himself inside a jar, so he will probably put something else in there that he can control, and to communicate with that creature he will have to create a [Telepathic Bond](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/telepathicBond.htm) and make it [Permanent](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/permanency.htm).

> You forge a telepathic bond among yourself and a number of willing
> creatures, each of which must have an Intelligence score of 3 or
> higher. Each creature included in the link is linked to all the
> others. The creatures can communicate telepathically through the bond
> regardless of language. No special power or influence is established
> as a result of the bond. Once the bond is formed, it works over any
> distance (although not from one plane to another).
>
> Telepathic bond can be made permanent with a permanency spell, though
> it only bonds two creatures per casting of permanency.

Now all that remains is a subject which will cooperate, and will not oppose the will of the Wizard. I suggest that you could use [Simulacrum](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/simulacrum.htm) to creature a virtual copy of the Wizard.

> Simulacrum creates an illusory duplicate of any creature. The
> duplicate creature is partially real and formed from ice or snow. It
> appears to be the same as the original, but it has only one-half of
> the real creature’s levels or Hit Dice (and the appropriate hit
> points, feats, skill ranks, and special abilities for a creature of
> that level or HD).
>
> At all times the simulacrum remains under your absolute command. No
> special telepathic link exists, so command must be exercised in some
> other manner.

There are possibly other ways to obtain the same sort of effect, but this one essentially places a double into the flask instead of projecting his image. The Wizard communicates with the double telepathically - and since the trapped double is playing along - can convince the party that it is indeed a real Wizard trapped in a flask. Of course, this method also *really does* trap someone in a flask, so it's not really a lie. :)

Comment: Great answer, fits my situation perfectly. Thankyou so much! :3

Comment: No problem, keep in mind these are high level spells. So that Wizard must be really bored if he is doing this just for mischief :)

Comment: And since it's not a 100% lie, the wizard doesn't even have to make a bluff check, if he's careful about his words ("it's just not the WHOLE truth"), which would be great since Bluff is not really on wizard's class list 8)

Comment: @Baka-Mastermind Bluff is for "convincing people of something unbelievable," not just for lying. You're right that not technically lying is a great defence against a number of forms of lie detection, though.

Answer (score 3):

A Wizard who sits in his tower can project himself to any location with the [Astral Projection](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/astralProjection.htm) spell.

Knowing when to Astrally Project towards the flask he claims is his prison is actually the tricky part. The spell *Watchware* (Unapproachable East, page 53) can take care of that - it is basically a high-level [Alarm](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/alarm.htm) spell with unlimited range and duration.

A flaw with this approach is that Watchware works once and is then discharged. I recommend lying that manifesting outside the lamp is very difficult for the Wizard. If he wants to appear again, he can Scry on the party and then Astrally Project again.

I also recommend a sprinkling of [Magic Aura](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicAura.htm) to make the lamp seem more magical (what spell it should emulate depends on what the Wizard wants to accomplish with these theatrics). It's not permanent, but a high level caster can make it last for weeks - plenty of time for mischief.